# Imposible to build an android version of my project with nme, haxe and flashdevelop

Tags: android, flashdevelop, haxe, nme

I’m trying to compile my nme project for android, but until this moment it has been impossible for me. The error message that I’m getting is

> Running process: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe
>   "C:\Users\Andrés\Documents\myOP\project.hxproj" -ipc
>   cf7bbe3a-8e0c-47e5-aac3-4d442ae964f2 -version "2.10" -compiler
>   "C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe" -notrace -library "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\FlashDevelop\Library" -target "android" Building project haxelib
>   run nme build "C:\Users\Andrés\Documents\myOP\project.nmml" android
>   haxelib run hxcpp Build.xml haxe -Dactuate -Dandroid -Dcpp
>   -Dfullscreen -Dhaxe_208 -Dhaxe_209 -Dhaxe_210 -Dmobile -Dnme -Dnme_install_tool -Dsys -Dtrue Creating obj/android/**pch/haxe/hxcpp.h.gch... arm-linux-androideabi-g++
>   -Iinclude --sysroot=C:\Users\Andrés\Documents\AndroidNDK/platforms/android-5/arch-arm
>   -IC:\Users\Andrés\Documents\AndroidNDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include
>   -IC:\Users\Andrés\Documents\AndroidNDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi/include
>   -DHXCPP_VISIT_ALLOCS -Dhaxe_210 -IC:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include -Iinclude -fpic -fvisibility=hidden -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -D__ARM_ARCH_5** -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D_LINUX_STDDEF_H  -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fomit-frame-pointer -fexceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=10000 -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -O2 -DNDEBUG -c -frtti -o obj/android/__pch/haxe/hxcpp.h.gch
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/hxcpp.h
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/hxcpp.h:14:20: error:
>   typeinfo: No such file or directory In file included from
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/hxcpp.h:193:
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/Array.h:205:21: error:
>   algorithm: No such file or directory In file included from
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/hxcpp.h:185:
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/hx/Object.h: In member
>   function 'void hx::ObjectPtr::CastPtr(hx::Object*)':
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/hx/Object.h:143: error:
>   must #include  before using typeid In file included from
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/hxcpp.h:193:
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/Array.h: In member
>   function 'void Array_obj::sort(Dynamic)':
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/Array.h:401: error:
>   'stable_sort' is not a member of 'std' In file included from
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/hxcpp.h:194:
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/Class.h: In function
>   'bool hx::TCanCast(hx::Object*)':
>   C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,1//include/Class.h:154: error: must
>
> ## include  before using typeid Called from ? line 1 Called from BuildTool.hx line 1529 Called from BuildTool.hx line 673 Called
>
> from BuildTool.hx line 708 Called from BuildTool.hx line 842 Called
>   from BuildTool.hx line 885 Called from BuildTool.hx line 194 Uncaught
>   exception - Error creating pch: 1 - build cancelled Error : Build
>   failed Build halted with errors (haxelib.exe). Done(1)

okay. I've already used the nme setup android command. My .hxcpp_config.xml file:

ANDROID_SDK: C:\Users\Andrés\Documents\eclipse+android\sdk

ANDROID_SETUP value = true

ANDROID_NDK_ROOT: C:\Users\Andrés\Documents\AndroidNDK

ANT_HOME: C:\Development\Apache Ant

JAVA_HOME value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11

And finally I verified my environmental variables. Here they are. User variables

HAXEPATH: C:\Motion-Twin\haxe\

NEKO_INSTPATH: C:\Motion-Twin\neko

PATH: ;%HAXEPATH%;%NEKO_INSTPATH%

system variables

Path: WINDOWS\system32;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

I added ;C:\Motion-Twin\haxe\;C:\Motion-Twin\neko to the system path variable, without succes. 
Im using nme 3.5.5, haxe 2.10 and flashdevelop 4.4.1. I've already used the haxelib upgrade command, so I'm updated.
Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try reconfiguring the android framework.

Delete the hxcpp config file.

Now run the command

```
nme setup android
```

Then select Android from the target listbox and it should work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what should I do in order to do that??

Answer (score 0):

Hey just to let you know. I found the problem! You'll see flashdevelop was looking  for the haxe files in C:\Users\Andrés\Documents\AndroidNDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include, so I went to that direction and surprise, the 4.4.3 folder was missing, so, i created it and put all the files form C:\Users\Andrés\Documents\AndroidNDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/ into the 4.4.3 folder and done. Hope this can help somebody